# Drupal webform - unique ID for submissions, but unique to THAT form

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-webform

One of my websites has a LOT of forms, and they are heavily used. This means that the Webform module's "SID" is rapidly approaching 1 million, as it notches up a +1 for every form submission across the entire site.

Is there not a form-specific submission ID which starts at 0 for every unique instance of a webform? I've looked at CID, but that seems to be form componant ID?

I guess I could make something to utilise a new SQL table, but it seems crazy this has been overlooked?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1084906 - can't really be done within the module, it needs to be custom-coded.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here some solutions so submissions are not saved in the database, avoiding the problem http://drupal.org/node/290448

Comment: Hiya, thanks for posting, but i'd like them saved in the DB too! The real issue is calculating the unique SID on a per-form basis.